# How do I create a dynamically generated breadcrumb in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Breadcrumb being the navigational element that is used to tell the user where they are on the site.

E.g.

Home >> Projects >> Stages >> Uploads.

Where home, projects, stages & uploads are separate controllers.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I use almost the same code for like 10 years... Wrote it first in ASP, then C#, PHP, and now Rails:

```
module NavigationHelper
    def ensure_navigation
        @navigation ||= [ { :title => 'Home', :url => '/' } ]
    end

    def navigation_add(title, url)
        ensure_navigation << { :title => title, :url => url }
    end

    def render_navigation
        render :partial => 'shared/navigation', :locals => { :nav => ensure_navigation }
    end
end
```

Then, in `shared/navigation.html.erb`:

```
<div class="history-nav">
    <% nav.each do |n| %>
        <%= link_to n[:title], n[:url] %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to yield(:title), request.path, :class => 'no-link' %>
</div>
```

Your regular view:

```
<% content_for :title, 'My Page Title' %>
<% navigation_add 'My Parent Page Title', parent_page_path %>
```

And your template:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> <%= yield :title %> </title>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <%= render_navigation %>
  ...
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is nice and DRY! Thanks. Will check it to make sure it works for me. Thanks!

Comment: Btw, for the first snippet, where should I add that? To my application controller?

Comment: The first is a new helper. You can add its code to any helper you want, but I like it on its own helper, `NavigationHelper`.

Comment: I love this method. I used nested layout before, your method is more adapted to Ruby-on-Rails3! Thank you

Comment: Hey this looks clean and simple. Going to try it out.

Comment: Good logic no need to depends on any another gems great work men.

Comment: how to do this if view can have two parents ?

Comment: @MrWater, you might have to wrap your `navigation_add` calls into some additional logic that can detect the correct parent. Or write a different view for each parent, and isolate the shared parts into a partial.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer can be updated without using `<% content_for :title, 'My Page Title' %>`

```
  <div class="history-nav">
    <% nav.each do |n| %>
      <% unless n.equal? nav.last %>
        <%= link_to n[:title], n[:url] %>            
      <% else %>
        <%= n[:title] %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```