# Dynamic generated breadcrump

Tags: ruby-on-rails, breadcrumbs

I am working on adding dynamic breadcrump to my project. I found some good gems but I accidentally run into [this nice post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289272/how-do-i-create-a-dynamically-generated-breadcrumb-in-rails-3).

So I worked with Fábio's Batista solution and tried to reproduce what he did. What I did was to:

1. create a Navigation controller (file is currently empty),
2. followed the instructions of his post
   I am getting this error: `undefined local variable or method 'nav'` on this line: `<% nav.each do |n| %>`

I am sure that I am missing code segments; for example this nav element was not defined and that is why i get this error. If you understood the general idea of Fábio's Batista solution can you give me any kind of hint of what he did so I can understand how to make this work?

Comment: Maybe you can share your code and the error message with us, so we can give you a more precisely answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also tried that technique, but didn't feel it was robust enough to give us the functionality we required

--

**Gem**

So instead, we focused on using a gem by a fellow StackOverflower called [`breadcrumbs_on_rails`](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails). I know you don't want to use it, but we have it working, so I'll show you how *we* do it:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
Class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    add_breadcrumb "home", :root_path
end

#app/controllers/pages_controller.rb
    add_breadcrumb "pages", pages_path
    def show
        @page = Page.find params[:id]
        add_breadcrumb @page.name, page_path(@page)
    end
end
```

This allows you to call the view helper:

```
<%= render_breadcrumbs %>
```

--

We used this because of the sporadic nature of some of our controllers / actions.